# stripe API with php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i want use stripe api to create simple payments for my website 
but i have error HTTP 500 error

this my index.php :

```
<?php require_once('./config.php'); ?>

<form action="charge.php" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-description="Access for a year"
          data-amount="5000"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
</form>
```

config.php

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_*******************",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_*******************"
);
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
```

and sriple library folder

please helpe me

Comment: I hope those aren't your live credentials

Comment: If they _are_ your real credentials, OP, please invalidate them _immediately_. You will have to generate new ones. These are now compromised forever.

Comment: What does you error log have?